# Raspberry Pi 2 BCM2836 working but new Raspberry Pi 2 BCM2837 stuck on Rainbow Screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot-issues, process

I have an old image from my Raspberry Pi 2 (Jessie Lite) and this works fine on my Raspberry Pi 2 running the BCM2836 processor, however I ordered a new Pi 2 and it seems that they have changed to the BCM2837 processor for the Pi 2.

http://hackaday.com/2016/11/21/the-raspberry-pi-2-gets-a-processor-upgrade/

When I boot the same SD card on the new Pi 2 it gets stuck on the rainbow screen.

I know I need to do an update using the old Pi 2 to get it to work on the new Pi 2, but what command do I need to update the absolute minimum for this to work?

Comment: How much work is `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: The problem with that is it updates all packages, not just the one that is required for the boot.

Comment: Not upgrading other packages is a big security isssue.

Comment: Yes, while not upgrading everything is not advised... for this instance, that's not an issue... Only getting the image to boot is the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the Kernel, to repair this without updating packages you don't want to touch run.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install raspberrypi-bootloader
```

This will update the bootloader package to the latest version without changing anything else.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network. Since you answered your own question you are allowed to mark it as the answer - you will even get the reputation points for it, which if you are just starting out here does help! 8-) Might I suggest you follow the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) link at the bottom of the page as it may help you to get a better experience here...

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you might minimise the changes.

I would use the following command to update the firmware`sudo rpi-update`.

Comment: "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911