# IncrediblePBX will not boot on newer versions of Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot

I have been running IncrediblePBX on an older version of Raspberry PI. I have made an image and copied to new micro SD card, but cannot get it to boot on newer versions of Raspberry Pi.

I have followed the instructions from https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16982376-updating-raspian-on-your-microsd-for-the-raspberry-pi-2 to upgrade the OS, but still will not boot on newer Pi.

I have also tried the recommendations from [Raspberry Pi 2 BCM2836 working but new Raspberry Pi 2 BCM2837 stuck on Rainbow Screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59156/raspberry-pi-2-bcm2836-working-but-new-raspberry-pi-2-bcm2837-stuck-on-rainbow-s), but when I run apt-get install raspberrypi-bootloader I receive "Module not found".

I ran the cmd cat /proc/cpuinfo on the working Pi and discovered I have Hardware-BCM2708 Revision 000e.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to get the microSD card to boot on a newer Pi. So far I've tried to boot it on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+, neither will boot.

Comment: `I have made an image and copied to new micro SD card` does this new card work on old Pi? How did you create the image for the new SD card?

Comment: I used Win32DiscImager to copy the SD card of the original system, then I used Balena Etcher to write to the new Micro SD card. I also tested by inserting the micro into an SD adapter and running on original Pi

Comment: does the windows readable partition on the SD have `kernel7.img` file?

Comment: There is a kernel.img, but no kernel7.img. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Must be as old image

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

I ran rpi-update. This updated the Kernel. I can now boot the Micro SD on newer Raspberry Pi models.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I did try sudo apt-get update; but I wasn't aware of sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel